# python isort problems - reverse order and sorting with "as"

Tags: python, isort

I downloaded and starting using isort, for Python. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/isort.

There's a few problems that I take issue with and I was hoping others might know the answer, because I'm not seeing anything in its docs or wiki.

### Python Alias Sorting

This is how isort will sort Python imports that use `as`.

Before:

```
from .core import check
from . import bridgebuilder as bridge
from . import plugin as plug
from . import common


from . import dict_classes
```

After:

```
from . import plugin as plug
from . import bridgebuilder as bridge
from . import common
from . import dict_classes
from .core import check
```

The idea here is that `as` statements get treated specially and placed on top. You can ignore this by adding `combine_as_imports` in the `.isort.cfg` file

Now it's this

After (combine_as_imports=1)

```
from . import common
from . import plugin as plug
from . import dict_classes
from . import bridgebuilder as bridge
from .core import check
```

Yikes. I get that the order is still technically ascending if you remove the `as` parts and just look at the module names but this isn't at all what I expected.

What I expected

```
from . import common
from .core import check
from . import dict_classes
from . import plugin as plug
from . import bridgebuilder as bridge
```

That way the eye moves in one direction (upper left to lower right) to read the names of each module/namespace. After all, I don't actually care about the module's name most of the time - I just care about the namespace needed to type something in the file.

### Not Enough Sorting options

I haven't found a way to sort in descending order yet.

This is what isort does

Before

```
import os
import itertools
import functools
import yamlordereddictloader

import six

import copy

from .core import check
from . import bridgebuilder
```

After (line length - ascending - alphabetical)

```
import os
import copy
import functools
import itertools

import six
import yamlordereddictloader

from .core import check
from . import bridgebuilder
```

What I wanted (line length - descending - alphabetical)

```
import functools
import itertools
import copy
import os

import yamlordereddictloader
import six 

from . import bridgebuilder
from .core import check
```

If anyone can explain any of these points to me and offer solutions, I'd be very grateful. Also, sorry for the wall of a post. I considered splitting into multiple questions but wasn't sure. Anyway, thank you for taking the time to read and reply.

Comment: "EOF is a standard \r" This doesn't make sense to me. Since when is `EOF` `\r`? If you mean EOL, then EOL hasn't been `\r` on any recent system (`\r\n` on Windows, `\n` on *nix and recent OSX). Please add the output of `od -c` on the file after `isort` has run through it.

Comment: You're right, I misunderstood what it was doing there

https://pastebin.com/kwWSKX8j

That said, if you know how to change its other features like the ways I described, I'd appreciate it and thanks for the clarification. I've edited my original post to remove the issue so it can be more concise